# How to prove that $1=2$ from $0<0$

Tags: logic

Maybe a simple question, but I heard that an inconsistent theory can imply everything. For example: How to prove that $1=2$ from $0<0$.

Comment: $0<0$ is not inconsistent. It is inconsistent if you add it to a theory which proves $\lnot(0<0)$. But you didn't specify such a theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks, here I mean the usual theory of numbers.

Comment: In the statement of your question you are mixing up the syntactic notion of consistency and the semantic notion of validity. Inconsistent theories imply everything **by definition**. Your example is an example of "ex falso quodlibet": the principle that anything follows from a single invalid statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple way:

Any statement of the type $$p\implies q,$$

where $p$ is equivalent to $False$, is by definition true. Also, the statement $0<0\wedge \neg(0<0)$ (equivalent to $False$), is true. Therefore, the statement $$(0<0 \wedge \neg(0<0)) \implies 1=2$$
is a true statement.

---

The more "intuitive" way:

It is simple to prove that $1\leq 2$, as this is true almost by definition.

You also know that if $ac \leq bc$ and $c>0$, then $a \leq c$.

Now, you know that $$0\leq 0\\
2 \cdot 0 \leq 1\cdot 0$$
and because $0>0$, we can now assume that $2\leq 1$.

---

Therefore, we have $1\leq 2$ and $2\leq 1$, meaing that $1=2$.

Answer (score 4):

In standard mathematics we can prove
$$ (b\cdot a = c \cdot a) \land (0<a) \implies b = c $$
In particular, by setting $a=0$, $b=1$, $c=2$ we get
$$ 0=0 \land 0<0 \implies 1 =2 $$
The first premise $0=0$ is certainly true, so if we assume $0<0$ the conclusion $1=2$ must be true too.